# How does independence of the basic bras affect the choice of numbers used to represent a ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, representation-theory

On page 54 of Dirac's book, 'The Principles of Quantum Mechanics', he states:

> Take an orthogonal representation with basic bras $\langle\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_u|$, labelled by parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_u$ whose domains are all real. Take a ket $|a\rangle$ and form its representative $\langle\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_u|a\rangle$. Now form the numbers $\lambda_1\langle\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_u|a\rangle$ and consider them as the representative of a new ket $|b\rangle$. **This is permissible since the numbers forming the representative of a ket are independent**, on account of the basis bras being independent.

Why would dependence of the numbers on one another make this representative invalid?

Comment: dependence of the numbers means the associated observables cannot be represented on the same basis simultaneouly